# Sass, color schemes with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

i read this article http://www.sitepoint.com/dealing-color-schemes-sass/ and I wanted to try to apply the method but I've a question: It's possible use this with a variable?

Ex. I use bootstrap and i wanna change only value (without assign a property) for $brand-primary, can i change this value with this method?

I've assigned a dynamic class on my body (  or ), and i wanna change a $brand-primary value for every class...

Another Ex.
If body class is "en" $brand-primary: red; if body class is "it" $brand-primary: blue; if body class is "fr" $brand-primary: green;

It's possible?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the cleanest way to accomplish this is to create a mixin, and then pass in theme color variables.

The theme mixin code takes in all necessary colors, as well as a name that corresponds to the body class:

```
@mixin theme($name, $brand-primary) {
  body.#{$name} {
    background-color: $brand-primary;
  }
}
```

Create a separate Sass partial for housing your theme color variables. In this case, it would look something like this:

```
$brand-primary: green;
```

Create as many of these files as you have themes.

Using the themes is then as simple as:

```
@import 'Themes/_theme-name.scss';
@include theme("theme-name", $brand-primary);
```

Bonus - if you need to apply styles to a specific theme, it's as easy as an @if statement in the mixin:

```
@if ($name == "theme-name") {
  .class-name {background-image: url(example.png);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I don't know what I have to work with what property and that's why I need to change only the value of the variable


Bootstrap has so many classes that would be difficult to manage in this way.

Thanks